# How to dynamically change the URL in Select2 using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ui-select2

I am using ui-select2 in angularjs for remote data access.
I am having a drop down, based on the value chosen in dropdown the URL present in the ajax call should change dynamically , so that I can get the data from that particular URL.

Is it possible to change the URL dynamically based on the value present in the dropdown?

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved this problem using function in ajax property:

```
ajax: {
            url: function () { return '/product/' +$scope.campaign.advertiser + '/tags/'; },
            ...
}
```