# Cannot access variable inside select2 AJAX URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have country and city `select` boxes. Content is loading to city box based on the country id. The problem is that AJAX URL always sees only the initial value of `countryId`, although I can access right value from other functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var countryId = 1;

    $(".country-select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a country",
        data: countries
    });

    $(".country-select").on("select2:select", function(e) {
        countryId = e.params.data["id"];
    });

    $(".city-select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a city",
        ajax: {
            //countryId always equals 1
            url: "https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCities?country_id=" + countryId,
            //other options
        }
    });

    $(".somediv").click(function() {
        alert(countryId); //alerts right value
    });
});
```

Comment: Answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28861300/2503246) question can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change the URL in Select2 using AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606403/how-to-dynamically-change-the-url-in-select2-using-ajax)